# REACT - bind with onchange input(child) and output(child) in the parent element

Tags: reactjs

there are two components

1. input - where the user will enter the value
2. there is an output (H1) where this value will be displayed immediately

These two components are displayed in the parent file where they are as an array and are displayed in different places in html.
Also in the parent file, there is a button that creates 1 input and 1 output, which interact with each other and are independent of the rest of the same.

So far, the main problem is that two components display what I need when rendering, but do not change the value

**Parrent**

```js
import InputTest from './InputTesting'
import TestOutput from './OutputTest'
const PageToCombine = () =>{
    const [title, setTitle] = useState('qwrqw!')
    const changeTitle = event => {
        setTitle(event.target.value);
    }

    const [inputItems, setInputItems] = useState([
        {id:32, type:"text", onchange:changeTitle, value:title},
    ])

    const [outputItems, setOutputItems] = useState([
        {id: 12, type:"text", value:title, onchange:changeTitle},    
    ])

   return(
        <div>
{inputItems.map((inputitem) =>
                <InputTest id={inputitem.id} type={inputitem.type} value={inputitem.value} onChange={inputitem.onchange}/>
            )}
            {outputItems.map(outputitem =>
                <TestOutput id={outputitem.id} type={outputitem.type} value={outputitem.value} onChange={outputitem.onchange}/>
            )}
</div>
    )
}
```

**TestOutput component**

```js
const TestOutput = (props) =>{

    console.log(props)
    return(
        <div>
            <h1 {...props} onChange = {props.onChange}>{props.value}</h1>
        </div>
    )
    
}
```

**InputTest component**

```js
const InputTest = (props) => {

    
    console.log(props)
    return(
        <input className={classes.inputTestStyle} {...props}/>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track to solving this problem, the key is to not pass a predefined `onChange` to the input but to generate one for each item. Thereby your parent is fully controlling your dynamic inputs.

[codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-moon-ltyc3f?file=/src/App.js)

```
export default function App() {
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState([
    { id: 0, type: "text", value: "qwrqw!" }
  ]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => setInputs((p) => [...p, { id: p.length, value: "" }])}
      >
        New item
      </button>
      <div>
        {inputs.map((input) => (
          <Input
            key={input.id}
            onChange={(value) => {
              setInputs((previous) =>
                previous.map((p) =>
                  p.id === input.id ? { ...input, value } : p
                )
              );
            }}
            value={input.value}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
      <div>
        {inputs.map((input) => (
          <Output key={input.id} value={input.value} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function Input({ onChange, value }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={(e) => onChange(e.currentTarget.value)} value={value} />
    </div>
  );
}

function Output({ value }) {
  return <h1>{value}</h1>;
}
```

Notice that an `id` is used to identify each item, this is by React recommendations to not use indices as keys in case the items are reordered. That also means it's up to you to generate a unique id.

Comment: THX. You are best want to be like you ))

Comment: Thanks for the compliment @RomanM! If my answer answered your question you can mark it as accepted by click the checkmark next to it so that others can find a working solution. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you try to use to many states you can just use one state for this

```js
const PageToCombine = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
    {
      id: 32,
      type: "text",
      value: "inital value",
    },
  ]);
  return (
    <div>
      {items.map((inputitem) => (
        <InputTest
          id={inputitem.id}
          type={inputitem.type}
          value={inputitem.value}
          onChange={(e) => {
            // set the value of the item with the same id as the input
            setItems((prevItems) => {
              return prevItems.map((item) => {
                if (item.id === inputitem.id) {
                  return { ...item, value: e.target.value };
                }
                return item;
              });
            });
          }}
        />
      ))}
      {items.map((outputitem) => (
        <TestOutput
          id="{outputitem.id}"
          type="{outputitem.type}"
          value="{outputitem.value}"
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using too many states and seems like you are not updating inputItems by setting setInputItems you should do like this with only one state for inputTest component and testOutput component

Parent component

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import InputTest from './InputTest';
import TestOutput from './TestOutput ';
export default function PageToCombine() {
const [title, setTitle] = useState('qwrqw!')
const [inputItems, setInputItems] = useState([
    { id: 32, type: "text", value: title },
    { id: 33, type: "text", value: title },
])
const onchangeItems = (e, index) => {
    let _inputItems = [...inputItems];
    _inputItems[index].value = e.target.value
    setInputItems(_inputItems)
}
return (
    <div>
        {inputItems.map((inputitem, index) =>
            <>
                <InputTest type={inputitem.type} value={inputitem.value} id=
                    {inputitem.id} onchange={(e) => onchangeItems(e, index)} />
                <TestOutput type={inputitem.type} value={inputitem.value} id=
                    {inputitem.id} />
            </>
        )}
    </div>
)
```

}

InputTest component

```
 export default function InputTest(props) {
   return (
    <input {...props} onChange={(e) => props.onchange(e,props.index)} />
   )
 }
```

Outputtest component

```
export default function TestOutput(props) {
   return (
     <div>
        <h1 {...props}>{props.value}</h1>
     </div>
   )
}
```